# Azure Table: Table design strategy

Tags: database-design, azure-table-storage

I am deciding between 2 Azure Table design strategy for storing data for multiple tenant

1. Have one table for each table. So for tenant 1 make it instance_1 for tenant 2 have instance_2. Pros for this is

   - Tenant data more separate from each other. Lesser risk of cross-tenant data corruption.
   - Deleting a tenant is easier
   - No. of indexable key is increased. Since I dont have to index with tenantId

   Cons for this is

   - Too many tables
   - Doesn't look right. If everything is same we shouldn't have separate table
   - Table Name will have tenant Id (Doesn't look so good)
   - If we don't have information on tenant Id then we need to search for all the tables. For that we need to store all the table name in a separate table
2. Keep partition Key as tenant Id and store all the tenant data in one table called Instances. 
   Pros

   - Similar structure of data resides in similar place.
   - Have partition per tenant
   - Easier to search entire table for a data where partition key is not known(As compared to haveing data per tenant).

What is the better design strategy in this case.

Comment: Since it has no cons whatsoever option 2 is clearly better.  Why are you asking this question ?

Comment: I cant think of any cons doesn't mean that this is better choice. I need help in deciding If I am not making any mistake in choosing 2.

Comment: Azure Table data modelling and partitioning strategies are very much based on your usage scenarios. Secondary concern is throughput and number of entities. So can you at least update your question with your use cases, query needs.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, choosing which design strategy is according to how to want to use the table storage.

If you don't want to search cross tenant and delete the data frequently in the table or your search data is little, I think you could chose the first design strategy.

If you want to use cross tenant search query with many tenant and search frequently, I suggest you could choose the second design strategy.

Notice: Table Scan performance(Cross table scan take time> Full table scan take time):
[image]

Besides, before considering the partition-key and row-key, I suggest you could firstly consider which result you will get and which query you will use.

According to the query, you could consider the right partition-key and row-key.

More details, you could refer to below article:
[Azure Storage Table Design Guide: Designing Scalable and Performant Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-table-design-guide)